# F#: Type mismatch error when trying to return my result from a function

Tags: f#, type-mismatch

So I have this function that calculates the frequency percentage of each letter given a string. this function is called "frequency" and utilizes other helper functions that I've wrote ("count", "lowerCases", and "percent"). But when I try to return my result, I keep getting a mismatch error. Here is my code below:

```
let frequency(str:string) : float  = 
    let myList = ['a'..'z']
    for i=0 to 25 do 
      printf "%f" (percent ((count myList.[i] str) (lowerCases str)))

System.Console.WriteLine(frequency"hello world")
```

I keep getting this error:

```
This expression was expected to have type float but here has type unit
```

How can I fix this type mismatch error? I've already tried setting my result to a different variable and calling that variable, but that didn't work.

Comment: Return value of a function is the very last line of the function body. What is the last line in your function body?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin it would be the float value that i'm printing after every iteration. I'm not sure what to put for the return value if I need to print something after every iteration.

Comment: @HiWorld567 You can return multiple values, one for each letter, by using a Map as the return type.  You can than iterate over that map to print the values, or print the values as you generate them inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared the function as returning a float:

```
let frequency(str:string) : float  =
```

However, your function doesn't return a float, it just prints one out:

```
printf "%f" (percent ((count myList.[i] str) (lowerCases str)))
```

The `printf` function returns `unit`, meaning that it effectively has no return value (it has a constant return value of the singleton type `unit`).

There are two things that I see you needing to fix here.  You need to return a value from the function (by having it be the value of the last line), and I think you will want your return type to be a list or a map instead of a single value (else, how would you know two which letter the frequency applies)?

You can achieve this result by just calling your `percent` function from `List.map`, and then making `Map` of the list:

```
let frequency(str:string) : Map<char, float>  = 
    ['a'..'z']
    |> List.map (fun letter -> letter, (percent ((count letter str) (lowerCases str))))
    |> Map.ofList
```

Answer (score 1):

An F# function binds a single value of the single expression in its body (the one which comes last after all `let`-bindings, simply speaking. In your case, this expression is

```
for i=0 to 25 do 
  printf "%f" (percent ((count myList.[i] str) (lowerCases str)))
```

It has the type `unit`, meaning it does not return anything useful but a special value `()`, while the `let frequency ... : float =` binding says that it returns a `float`. Hence the error.

`printf` already prints to console. What you want is probably

```
let frequency(str:string) : unit  = 
    let myList = ['a'..'z']
    for i=0 to 25 do 
      printf "%f" (percent ((count myList.[i] str) (lowerCases str)))

do frequency "hello world"
```

It is idiomatic to omit the `: unit` annotation in such a function, and let the compiler infer the return type. This code does not shine the F# glory, naturally, but does the job.

As it appears you are learning the language, here's an exercise, maybe for the future. Your function lumps together *computing* the letter frequencies and *printing* them, and functional programming is all about composition. What if you want to display the result in a window instead of printing it to console, or format it differently? Try to write two functions, one returning a data structure with the letter frequencies, and another printing it.